# pyqt5 открыть новое окно или новый файл из главного окна и передать параметры

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать. Есть главный файл **main.py**, в результате работы выводится список из компьютеров. Нажимая на кнопку `Diag` в `tableWidget` нужно открывать новый файл **pos_diag.py** (сделанный в *Qt Desinger*, потому-что в файл будет добавляться новый функционал, а руками мне будет сложно\долго все прописывать) и передавать в него параметры (`ip, n, num`) из **main.py** для подключения к отсканированным ПК и вывода информации.

Встал на том как передать параметры. А лучше всего еще и реализовать при нажатии на кнопку `Diag` создание новой вкладки в **pos_diag.py** чтобы работать с многими ПК в одном окне либо просто открывать каждый раз новую копию **pos_diag.py**.

Приложени(я)е будет скомпилировано в `*.exe`

Как вариант открывать скопилированный файл, но в него надо как-то передать аргуметы, и минус в том что таких файлов будет открыто много если работать без создания вкладок в `pos_diag.py`

```
def pos_log(self):
    os.startfile(r'.\pos_diag.exe')
```

```
###main.py### главное окно

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.rows = [
            ('10.16.26.25', 2),
            ('10.16.26.26', 3),
            ('10.16.26.27', 1),
            ('10.16.26.28', 4)
        ]
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            placeholderText='Введите номер из 4х цифр')
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.func_connect)  #прикрутим Enter после ввода в lineedit

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('SCAN')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func_connect)

        #Combobox
        self.cmbState = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)

        self.cmbState.currentTextChanged.connect(self.WK_VNC)     

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 5)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['IP', 'Num', 'SSH', 'VNC', 'Diag'])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(150)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        vbox.addWidget(self.cmbState) #add combobox

    def func_connect(self):
        num = self.lineEdit.text()   #текст нужно передать в pos_diag.py

        #список для добавления в combobox
        wk_list = [
            ['Выберите PC для подключения'],
            ['pc1', '10.20.35.25'],
            ['pc2', '10.20.35.26'],
            ['pc3', '10.20.35.27']
        ]

        self.cmbState.clear()
        for w in wk_list:
            self.cmbState.addItem(* w)                      

        if not num.isdigit():
            self.parent.statusBar().showMessage(
                'Достустимо вводить только цифры, номер состоит из 4х цифр')
            return
        if len(num) != 4 :
            self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('Номер состоит из 4х цифр, повторите ввод.')
            return
        self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('')

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.rows))
        for row, items in enumerate(self.rows):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'SSH {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_SSH(ip, n, btn))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 2, button)

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'VNC {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_VNC(ip, n, btn))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 3, button)

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Diag {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_VNC(ip, n, btn))   #текст нужно передать в pos_diag.py
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 4, button)

        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        index = self.parent.tabWidget.currentIndex()        
        self.parent.tabWidget.setTabText(index, num)        


    def button_pushed_SSH(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}, lineEdit={self.lineEdit.text()}')

    def button_pushed_VNC(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}, lineEdit={self.lineEdit.text()}')

    def WK_VNC(self, txt):
        currentData = self.cmbState.currentData()
        if currentData:
            print(f'данные для текущего элемента {txt} --> {currentData}')


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        count = self.tabWidget.count()
        self.nb = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text="Добавить", autoRaise=True)
        self.nb.clicked.connect(self.new_tab)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(count, QtWidgets.QWidget(), "")
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(
            count, QtWidgets.QTabBar.RightSide, self.nb)

        self.new_tab()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_tab)

    def new_tab(self):
        index = self.tabWidget.count() - 0
        tabPage = MyTab(self)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, tabPage, f"Tab {index}")
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        tabPage.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def close_tab(self, index):
        if self.tabWidget.count() > 2:
            self.tabWidget.removeTab(index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Ubuntu", 11, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    win = MyWindow()
    win.resize(720, 480)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
###pos_diag.py### второе окно открывающееся при нажатии кнопки Diag

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile, QTextStream
import diag2
import paramiko

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, diag2.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Diag")

        btn_press = "QPushButton:pressed{background-color: rgb(43, 153, 131)}"

        self.SMART_HDD.clicked.connect(lambda: self.CMD('10.20.20.5', 'ls -la /')) #вместо IP адреса нужно передать ip из main.py
        self.SMART_HDD.setStyleSheet(btn_press)

        self.POSinfo.clicked.connect(lambda: self.CMD('10.20.20.5', 'sudo dmidecode -t1')) 
#вместо IP адреса нужно передать ip из main.py
        self.POSinfo.setStyleSheet(btn_press)

#функция для подключения событий кнопкам
    def CMD(self, ip, command):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname=ip, username='login', password='passwd', timeout=2)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
        data = stdout.read().decode('utf-8') + stderr.read().decode('utf-8')
        print(data)
        self.textBrowser.setText(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Ubuntu", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    win = MyWindow()
    win.resize(800, 550)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
#import diag2 скомпилирован из QtDesinger
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(752, 532)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 581))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.tab)
        self.tabWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 749, 487))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.tabWidget_2.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.tabWidget_2.setObjectName("tabWidget_2")
        self.posdiag = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.posdiag.setObjectName("posdiag")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.posdiag)
        self.textBrowser.setEnabled(True)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(97, 0, 651, 461))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textBrowser.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textBrowser.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textBrowser.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.posdiag)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 91, 429))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.POSinfo = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.POSinfo.setObjectName("POSinfo")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.POSinfo)
        self.X11VNC = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.X11VNC.setObjectName("X11VNC")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.X11VNC)
        self.SMART_HDD = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.SMART_HDD.setObjectName("SMART_HDD")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.SMART_HDD)
        self.frinfo = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.frinfo.setObjectName("frinfo")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frinfo)
        self.Network = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.Network.setObjectName("Network")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Network)
        self.update = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.update.setObjectName("update")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.update)
        self.error = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.error.setObjectName("error")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.error)
        self.error_scale = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.error_scale.setObjectName("error_scale")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.error_scale)
        self.error_fr = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.error_fr.setObjectName("error_fr")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.error_fr)
        self.syslog = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.syslog.setObjectName("syslog")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.syslog)
        self.lsusb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.lsusb.setObjectName("lsusb")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lsusb)
        self.date_install = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.date_install.setObjectName("date_install")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.date_install)
        self.cash_reload = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.cash_reload.setObjectName("cash_reload")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.cash_reload)
        self.pos_reboot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pos_reboot.setObjectName("pos_reboot")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pos_reboot)
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.posdiag, "")
        self.NetScan = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.NetScan.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.NetScan.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.NetScan.setObjectName("NetScan")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.NetScan)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 91, 411))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_8)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.NetScan)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(97, 0, 626, 411))
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.NetScan, "")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.tabWidget_2.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.POSinfo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "POS info"))
        self.X11VNC.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X11VNC"))
        self.SMART_HDD.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Smart HDD"))
        self.frinfo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FR info"))
        self.Network.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Network"))
        self.update.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Update"))
        self.error.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Error"))
        self.error_scale.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Error Scale"))
        self.error_fr.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Error FR"))
        self.syslog.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sysylog"))
        self.lsusb.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "lsusb"))
        self.date_install.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Date install"))
        self.cash_reload.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cash reload"))
        self.pos_reboot.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "POS reboot"))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.posdiag), _translate("MainWindow", "   POS Diag  "))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.NetScan), _translate("MainWindow", "   NetScan   "))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "POS-1")) 
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "POS-2"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "POS-3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен что правильно вас понял, но предложу попробовать:

**main.py**

```
###main.py### главное окно

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from q1314624_pos_diag import MyWindow as PosDiag              # +++ PosDiag


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.rows = [
            ('10.16.26.25', 2),
            ('10.16.26.26', 3),
            ('10.16.26.27', 1),
            ('10.16.26.28', 4)
        ]
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            placeholderText='Введите номер из 4х цифр')
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.func_connect)  #прикрутим Enter после ввода в lineedit

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('SCAN')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func_connect)

        #Combobox
        self.cmbState = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)

        self.cmbState.currentTextChanged.connect(self.WK_VNC)     

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 5)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['IP', 'Num', 'SSH', 'VNC', 'Diag'])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(150)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        vbox.addWidget(self.cmbState) #add combobox

    def func_connect(self):
        num = self.lineEdit.text()   #текст нужно передать в pos_diag.py

        #список для добавления в combobox
        wk_list = [
            ['Выберите PC для подключения'],
            ['pc1', '10.20.35.25'],
            ['pc2', '10.20.35.26'],
            ['pc3', '10.20.35.27']
        ]

        self.cmbState.clear()
        for w in wk_list:
            self.cmbState.addItem(* w)                      

        if not num.isdigit():
            self.parent.statusBar().showMessage(
                'Достустимо вводить только цифры, номер состоит из 4х цифр')
            return
        if len(num) != 4 :
            self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('Номер состоит из 4х цифр, повторите ввод.')
            return
        self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('')

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.rows))
        for row, items in enumerate(self.rows):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'SSH {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_SSH(ip, n, btn))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 2, button)

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'VNC {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_VNC(ip, n, btn))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 3, button)

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Diag {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_VNC(ip, n, btn))   
                #текст нужно передать в pos_diag.py
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 4, button)

        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        index = self.parent.tabWidget.currentIndex()        
        self.parent.tabWidget.setTabText(index, num)        


    def button_pushed_SSH(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}, lineEdit={self.lineEdit.text()}')

    def button_pushed_VNC(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}, lineEdit={self.lineEdit.text()}')

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv       
        if btn.text()[0:4] == 'Diag':
            print(f'----------------  {ip}') #
            self.posDiag = PosDiag(ip)
            self.posDiag.show()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def WK_VNC(self, txt):
        currentData = self.cmbState.currentData()
        if currentData:
            print(f'данные для текущего элемента {txt} --> {currentData}')


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        count = self.tabWidget.count()
        self.nb = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text="Добавить", autoRaise=True)
        self.nb.clicked.connect(self.new_tab)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(count, QtWidgets.QWidget(), "")
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(
            count, QtWidgets.QTabBar.RightSide, self.nb)

        self.new_tab()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_tab)

    def new_tab(self):
        index = self.tabWidget.count() - 0
        tabPage = MyTab(self)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, tabPage, f"Tab {index}")
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        tabPage.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def close_tab(self, index):
        if self.tabWidget.count() > 2:
            self.tabWidget.removeTab(index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Ubuntu", 11, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    win = MyWindow()
    win.resize(720, 480)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1314624_pos_diag.py**

```
###pos_diag.py### второе окно открывающееся при нажатии кнопки Diag

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile, QTextStream

#import paramiko                              # это раскомментируете

#from diag2 import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(752, 532)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 581))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.tab)
        self.tabWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 749, 487))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.tabWidget_2.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.tabWidget_2.setObjectName("tabWidget_2")
        self.posdiag = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.posdiag.setObjectName("posdiag")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.posdiag)
        self.textBrowser.setEnabled(True)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(97, 0, 651, 461))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textBrowser.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textBrowser.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textBrowser.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.posdiag)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 91, 429))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.POSinfo = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.POSinfo.setObjectName("POSinfo")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.POSinfo)
        self.X11VNC = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.X11VNC.setObjectName("X11VNC")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.X11VNC)
        self.SMART_HDD = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.SMART_HDD.setObjectName("SMART_HDD")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.SMART_HDD)
        self.frinfo = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.frinfo.setObjectName("frinfo")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frinfo)
        self.Network = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.Network.setObjectName("Network")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Network)
        self.update = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.update.setObjectName("update")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.update)
        self.error = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.error.setObjectName("error")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.error)
        self.error_scale = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.error_scale.setObjectName("error_scale")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.error_scale)
        self.error_fr = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.error_fr.setObjectName("error_fr")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.error_fr)
        self.syslog = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.syslog.setObjectName("syslog")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.syslog)
        self.lsusb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.lsusb.setObjectName("lsusb")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lsusb)
        self.date_install = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.date_install.setObjectName("date_install")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.date_install)
        self.cash_reload = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.cash_reload.setObjectName("cash_reload")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.cash_reload)
        self.pos_reboot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pos_reboot.setObjectName("pos_reboot")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pos_reboot)
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.posdiag, "")
        self.NetScan = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.NetScan.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.NetScan.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.NetScan.setObjectName("NetScan")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.NetScan)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 91, 411))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_8)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.NetScan)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(97, 0, 626, 411))
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.NetScan, "")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.tabWidget_2.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.POSinfo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "POS info"))
        self.X11VNC.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X11VNC"))
        self.SMART_HDD.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Smart HDD"))
        self.frinfo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FR info"))
        self.Network.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Network"))
        self.update.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Update"))
        self.error.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Error"))
        self.error_scale.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Error Scale"))
        self.error_fr.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Error FR"))
        self.syslog.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sysylog"))
        self.lsusb.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "lsusb"))
        self.date_install.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Date install"))
        self.cash_reload.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cash reload"))
        self.pos_reboot.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "POS reboot"))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.posdiag), _translate("MainWindow", "   POS Diag  "))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.NetScan), _translate("MainWindow", "   NetScan   "))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "POS-1")) 
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "POS-2"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "POS-3"))
        


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ip):
        super().__init__()
        print(f'================  {ip}') #
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Diag")
        

        btn_press = "QPushButton:pressed{background-color: rgb(43, 153, 131)}"


        self.SMART_HDD.clicked.connect(
# вместо IP адреса нужно передать ip из main.py
#            lambda: self.CMD('10.20.20.5', 'ls -la /')) 
            lambda: self.CMD(ip, 'ls -la /')) 
        self.SMART_HDD.setStyleSheet(btn_press)

        self.POSinfo.clicked.connect(
# вместо IP адреса нужно передать ip из main.py
#             lambda: self.CMD('10.20.20.5', 'sudo dmidecode -t1')) 
            lambda: self.CMD(ip, 'sudo dmidecode -t1'))

        self.POSinfo.setStyleSheet(btn_press)

#функция для подключения событий кнопкам
    def CMD(self, ip, command):
    
        '''  это раскомментируете
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname=ip, username='login', password='passwd', timeout=2)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
        data = stdout.read().decode('utf-8') + stderr.read().decode('utf-8')
        print(data)
        '''
        data = f'ip = {ip}, command = {command}'  # это для теста, уберете
        self.textBrowser.setText(data)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Низкий поклон за помощь! Конструкция работает, попробую перевести все в exe и передать значения

Comment: @elchako удачи вам.

Comment: @S.Ncik могу ли я связаться с вами лично, например по почте?

Comment: @elchako если у вас есть какие-либо вопросы, задайте их на SO, чем смогу - помогу.